# Push multiple objects with 2 properties into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a prescription form for doctors,
It have to be posible to add new medicines with dosis instructions, so I dynamically add two inputs every time the doctor click on add another. But I cant get to handle change to push the object with both inputs into an array 
I'm trying to get something like this:

```
dosis: [
    {
        name: medicine1,
        instructions: every 6 hrs
    },
    {
        name: medicine2,
        instructions: every 8 hrs
    }
]
```

This is my parent component where child components are added:

```
<ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild}>
    <div className="form-group col-md-6 align-middle">                                        
        <label>Medicine name:</label>
        <Search
             data={ this.state.data }
             onChange={ this.handleChangeComponent.bind(this) }
             placeholder="Search for a string..."
             class="search-class  upperinput"
             searchKey="name"
             value={this.state.name}
             ref="medicine"

         />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group col-md-6 align-middle">
        <label for="medicamento-search">Indicaciones y Duración del Tx:</label>                                                                      
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instructions" ref="instructions" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.instructions} placeholder="Instructions.."/>
                                </div>
    {children}
</ParentComponent>
```

The Search component its a Autocomplete searchbar so I handle change like this:

```
handleChangeComponent(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e });
  }
```

The instructions input its a normal input so handler is:

```
 handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

Also this is how I'm adding childs to parentComponent

```
   onAddChild = () => {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }
    render() {

    const children = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
      children.push(<MedicineSearch data={this.state.data} searchKey="name" key={i} number={i} value={this.state.name} onChange={ this.handleChangeComponent.bind(this) }/>);
    };
    return (... My HTML )


const ParentComponent = props => (

    <div className="col-md-12 row" id="children-pane">
        {props.children}
    </div>
);
```

Here is a CodeSandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zwr101okom

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow alexrc94! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: It works, but I need it with the search bar,  I'm having trouble to make it work with it

Answer (score 0):

You can put `dosis` in your state and then add a new object with a `name` and `instructions` property when you click the add button, and finally loop over this array in the render method.

**Example**

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ name: "Adderall" }, { name: "Xanax" }],
    loading: false,
    dosis: [
      {
        name: "test medicine",
        instructions: "every 6 hrs"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const dosis = [...prevState.dosis];
      dosis[index] = { ...dosis[index], [name]: value };
      return { dosis };
    });
  };

  onAddChild = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        dosis: [
          ...prevState.dosis,
          {
            name: "new medicine",
            instructions: "some instruction"
          }
        ]
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dosis.map((element, i) => (
          <div>
            <div> Medicine Name </div>
            <input
              value={element.name}
              name="name"
              onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)}
            />
            <div> Instructions </div>
            <input
              value={element.instructions}
              name="instructions"
              onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.onAddChild}>Add Dosis</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: When I tried to use it with the search component, it crashed with: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined,
Is there a way to set name to the input of that component? the dependency is react-search-bar

Comment: @alexrc94 No, you can't. But you can use the [`onChange` of the search component and get the search term and use that directly](https://github.com/vakhtang/react-search-bar/blob/aa663a0927ea4bf0dd2b63f5c0f8c45dd3e74ea5/src/components/search-bar.js#L94).

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I'm trying to make your example work with react-autosuggest